# Testing Graphical Users Interfaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a fancy GUI in jQuery, which has gotten relatively complex. I would like to write tests for it, e.g. using `assert()`. However, it seems that writing such tests is difficult because GUIs don't manipulate data or make computations: they are just superficial interfaces to please the user.

So how does one generally write tests for GUIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your code is fairly clean (modular and loosely coupled pieces of functionality that work together rather then a few uber functions), the first thing to do is choose a test framework. I recommend [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/), because it fits the way I like to write tests, but if you are looking for more of an xUnit clone, [qunit](http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit) is also very well made.

If your code is not pulled apart (like 99.99% of javascript in the wild), I would first look at how to make [jquery plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), and extract as much as you can into them. Testing uber-functions that do loads of things is a scary proposition, but when you are talking about a module that does a single thing, testing gets much easier.

Finally, there is a bit of a learning curve with both how to structure complex javascript, and how to test it. Don't give up! Contrary to what some people would have you believe, javascript is very testable nowadays with very solid libraries and there are many people doing it (I just spent all day working on complex functionality, was practicing TDD the entire time, and it never felt clunky or unnatural)

Good luck, and feel free to ask for clarification if something here is unclear :)

EDIT:

By "pull apart" I mean move to a more modular approach rather then gigantic functions. In jQuery, the first step is with plugins, which will take you pretty far. If you are making a javascript "application", where most of your logic is in the front end and the back end is mostly for persistance, I would look at stuff like Backbone.js, which will help manage a very high level of complexity, but is totally overkill if you don't need it.

Going back to extracting plugins, try to find pieces of functionality that are sort of contained. I wrote a quick plugin today to remember the state of checkboxes in a table with paging, where the contents of the table get swapped out programmatically, but if a user checks a box on page one (but doesn't save), goes to page two, then back to page one they should still see that box checked.

If that checkbox code was inline in the paging code, it would make the paging code WAY more complicated. By pulling it into a plugin, it only complicates the paging code a little bit (calling $(table).saveCheckState() when a page unloads, and $(table).loadCheckState() when a   new page loads) It also makes the testing very straightforward, all I need is a div with a few checkboxes to test the checkbox code, rather then needing to add more to the paging tests which are already pretty complex.

Not knowing your background or level of experience I would hesitantly recommend reading [clean code](http://www.amazon.ca/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) if you want to learn more about this sort of stuff. Unfortunately is it java oriented rather then javascript, but most of it is universally applicable in any object oriented language (which javascript *can* be), and is probably the best intro level book into this topic. If you do full stack development (rather then just front end), have at least a working knowledge of java, are a junior/intermediate dev who wants to improve their craft, its one of those books everyone should read. If those things aren't true, it may end up just being confusing, or just not really be much use to you. So take the recommendation with a grain of salt :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I have two questions. What do you mean by "pulled apart code"? Also, do you have tips about structuring complex javascript nicely?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in GUI itself - **User** interface.

GUI's are best tested with people. You should check out http://ux.stackexchange.com which is dedicated entirely to the user experience.

I think this is important, because I'm sure your GUI is to the point where it is solid, as you've done the unit testing on non-graphical elements. Through your own testing you've made it this way - now, you should see how other people interact with it, how they break it, and what they like or don't like about it. Then you make changes and do it all over again.

(Ok, I know this isn't unit testing. But seriously, the options out there for heavy testing of jQuery stuff are not that fun to deal with!)